# Amazon SDK Pod won't compile?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, cocoapods

I'm attempting to getting the Amazon iOS SDK integrated into my application and using the cocoapod to install it.

However, it won't compile, I'm getting an error inside of AmazonS3Client.h that says

> 'AWKRuntime/AmazonWebServiceClient.h' file not found

but it is clearly there in the Pod when I search for it.

Anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Same problem, but I'm not using CocoaPods.

Answer (score 9):

*Note: This answer refers to [a now deprecated version of the AWS SDK for iOS](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios-v1).*

---

I ran into the same problem when migrating a project to CocoaPods. Without modifying any of the AWS header files, I was able to avoid by changing my header import lines from:

```
#import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>
#import <AWSSNS/AWSSNS.h>
```

to:

```
#import <AmazonS3Client.h>
#import <AmazonSNSClient.h>
```

This works because all that `AWSS3.h` does is `#define AWS_MULTI_FRAMEWORK` and then `#import "AmazonSNSClient.h"`, and AWS_MULTI_FRAMEWORK is responsible for the other header files expecting a different directory structure than what CocoaPods sets up.

To find out what file names you need to include, just look inside the `AWS*.h` file you were importing and then import the files named inside directly.

Comment: can you explain more briefly

Comment: #import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>
#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h> but I am getting no such file was found I installed through coocapods

Comment: @JaswanthKumar The AWS SDK was rewritten since this was posted; v2 is completely different than v1. You might want to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

When using the cocoapod for AWS it has this in the separate framework headers:

```
#ifndef AWS_MULTI_FRAMEWORK
#define AWS_MULTI_FRAMEWORK
#endif
```

That makes it look to other frameworks instead of the relative path for the headers for shared frameworks.

If you comment those lines out, it will work.